# Material Design: Toolbar Drawer Icon Bad Quality on Xperia Phones

Tags: android, sony-xperia

I have a problem and I have not been able to find solution, probably problem appears only on Xperia phones, I do not own other devices so I can not confirm this, but for two Xperia models I can confirm strange behavior of navigation drawer icon on new Material Design Toolbar. Take a look at screenshot, everything you have to see is captured:

http://postimg.org/image/m8hzsz3zd/

So on Xperia M2 all toolbar drawer icon have blurred lines, on my app I have partially fix the problem by software layer type, but still not satisfying solution, on Xperia S lines are not blurred but last one is rounded? While Google Keep, Hangouts and Gmail have normal icons, youtube and others do not.

Any ideas how to fix this ugly problem....